# Nodejs readdirSync to get directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I am trying to use `readdirSync` to get directory's contents using an absolute file path: `"~/code/ft/FullStack-Lesson-Plans/01-Class-Content"`

I am using it like this:

```
let tempUnits = fs.readdirSync("~/code/ft/FullStack-Lesson-Plans/01-Class-Content");
```

I get this error:

```
(node:8736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './~/code/
ft/FullStack-Lesson-Plans/01-Class-Content'
(node:8736) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will termin
```

I am 100% that the path is correct.

How do I use `readdirSync` to get a directory's contents with an absolute file path?

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths you pass to node `fs` functions cannot contain shell-specific items (e.g. tildes or variables) because they are passed to the operating system directly (which the OS does not know about such special shell tokens). So either use an absolute or relative path instead.

Comment: So how would I write it then?

Comment: I got it!! Thank you that was it I changed it to
`let tempUnits = fs.readdirSync("/Users/besteman/code/ft/FullStack-Lesson-Plans/01-Class-Content");`

Answer (score 0):

I changed it do

```
let tempUnits = fs.readdirSync("/Users/besteman/code/ft/FullStack-Lesson-Plans/01-Class-Content");`
```

As @mscdex said it, does not accept `~`.